# TFS2010 accounts

Tags: tfs

I have created several local accounts in my server, and set password for them. Now, I distribute these accounts to my team members, I wish every one can change their own password, how can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2011/11/23/frequently-used-commands-during-tfs-2010-troubleshooting.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can login to the desktop of that server and change their password like they would on their own machine.  In order to access the desktop of that machine remotely they will need permissions.  One way to ensure they have the permission for that is to go to the properties of the computer and enter their names or groups to the remote users:

[image: System Properties - Remote Tab in Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1]

Comment: Thank you! It really made the users to change their own passwords, but it made them have the permission to the all server resource. Is there any other solutions, thank you again!

Comment: What do you mean by "all the server resources"? There are ways to limit the permission more to the server, through security settings and the local security policy,  but none of this is related to TFS;  rather, it is more system administration work. An Active Directory domain is likely more appropriate for the level of control you are seeking to have over the user accounts.

Comment: If I adopt domain, I think I need another server for domain control, but I have only one server.